# $k$ such that $n,2n,\dots,kn$ have odd sum of digits

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

is the following statement true or not?

for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that all numbers $n,2n,\dots,kn$ have odd sum of digits?

I have no idea... it may turn out hard (for even sum of digits it would be very easy)

Comment: Maybe something based on cyclic numbers?

Comment: Never mind, scratch that.  Apparently, it hasn't been proven that an infinite number of cyclic numbers exist.

Comment: Why is it easy for even sum of digits (if you require $n > 0$)?

Comment: @user73985: Because then $n=100\ldots001$ works whenever $n>k+1$.

Comment: using @user73985's idea, suppose that there is an $n$ which verifies $n,2n,\cdots,kn$ have odd sum of digits then there is an infinity of $a$ which verifies the same property $n_i=10^in$ works, so this means that we can work in the set of numbers not divisible by $10$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** : if we consider the number $n=9\cdots9$ with $2k-1$ of $9$'s. so for every element $0\leq i\leq 10^k$ we have the sum of digits of $ik$ is odd (is equal to 9(2k-1)) which proves your statement. I will provide a proof if this is necessary.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** Having an odd sum of digits means is equivalent to the condition that the number mod 9 is odd. This means that it's sufficient to consider $n \in \{0,\ldots,8\}$.

Comment: That's not right. For instance, $19$ mod $9$ is odd, but the sum of its digits is even.

Comment: This is wrong, 10 = 19 mod 9 but 10 has odd sum of digits while 19 has even.

Comment: Maybe he wants to say $mod 11 $ but it's not like he announced it, I checked that working $mod 11$ is a good idea but it doesn't help either.